# Get the domain of the website requesting for JS file

Tags: javascript

I want to get the domain of the website that requested for the Javascript file. Let say I have a script.js file in my server, then we have another website that gets this JS file. How can I get the domain of that website? I want to do that inside my script.js. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: I think this question needs a little more info.  Are you trying to get that information stored on your server somehow? The suggestions about location assume that you are trying to get the domain on the client side, but it sounds like maybe you want this information sent back from that website to your server? If thats what you want, an ajax request to an endpoint you've set up that stores the data in a database might be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the top level domain of the site that is including the script, it should be available as:

```
document.location.host
```